# Convertendo E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy para dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss c#

Tags: c#, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Estou recebendo a seguinte data `Thu Sep 01 00:00:00 BRT 2016` e preciso converter para `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Só que o convert gera erro, estou recebendo essa data via `string` de um Sistema.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
DateTime dtPeca;
dtPeca = Convert.ToDateTime(linha[4]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem certeza que o formato será sempre o mesmo, pode fazer a conversão usando [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime dateValue;
DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss BRT yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
```

Comment: Sim a Data é sempre nesse formato, então tenho que fazer a conversão.
essa "data" eu coloco o valor que eu recebo ?

Comment: @RenanSilveira Sim, pois foi o que eu fiz na minha resposta.

Comment: o valor de saida do dateValue é o valor inicial (01/01/0001), ele não pega o valor convertido.

Comment: @RenanSilveira Então é porque a string de entrada não está formato que você postou na pergunta ***=)***

Comment: "Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 BRST 2017" Esse é o valor que eu reccebo

Comment: @RenanSilveira Compare com o valor que você pôs na pergunta e vai ver a diferença. Depois é só adaptar na resposta e tudo vai funcionar normalmente.